# How to install AMD drivers on XUbuntu 15.10?

Tags: ati

How can i install AMD/ATI drivers on XUbuntu 15.10? I follow this guide, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlV3dsIYwxQ but after this i can't boot.

Answer (score 0):

First boot to [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and remove the drivers from terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

Now you can reboot to your desktop and [follow this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx) to install the drivers (I know you have 15.10 but the 14.04 solution will work.)